# Junit testing a class which extends WizardPage

Tags: java, testing, plugins, junit, wizard

I am tasked with trying to create a Junit test suite of a class which extends  'WizardPage'.

```
  public class PageDataModel extends WizardPage
```

Every time I try and create an object of this class within my test suit, the value of the page is null. 
Below is an example of a test I'm trying to execute.

```
    @Test
public void testEntityName() {
    PageDataModel pageDataModel = new PageDataModel("testing"); 
    pageDataModel.setContents("person");        
    String temp = pageDataModel.getContents();      
    assertEquals("person",temp );
}
```

Could someone please suggest where I'm going wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: What is `WizardPage`? Is this some semi-standard library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage`, you need to check your `setContents()` and `getContents()` methods (as far as I remember, `WizardPage` does not provide that method to you).

Do you store the `String` you pass in `setContents()` anywhere? Do you return that content in `getContents()`?

Comment: Are you sure this is an *Answer* and not a *Comment*?

Comment: I was thinking the same when I wrote it. But then I thought that pointing out the fact that the error might be in `setContents()` or `getContents()` could be a solution.